# Does Visual Basic's DateTime.Now create a new instance each time it is called?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Basically what the title says. I don't want to create a bunch of instances if I don't need to

edit : The documentation says "The Now property returns a DateTime value that represents the current date and time on the local computer." but i cant tell if that means it creates a new DateTime instance or references a pre-existing one

Comment: The word "instance" only applies to objects.  DateTime is a value type, it doesn't create an object.  Now returns a *value*, as the docs say, indistinguishable from a Long to the processor.  Not uncommon in the Release build that it doesn't require any storage at all, it fits in the processor registers.  Trying to optimize it can only make it worse.

Comment: If you use `DateTime.Now` and then a few seconds pass you will get a different value for `DateTime.Now` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` is a structure and each time you call the shared property `Now`, it does indeed create a new `DateTime` value. It's not a large structure (8 bytes, I believe) so there is no need to avoid creating as many as you need.